# How to use nested IF statements in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I am attempting to put the following flow into an equation in Google Sheets:

- Compare string from a given cell (cell 1)
- If the string is "A" evaluate a different cell (cell 2) under these conditions
- If its not "A" and the string is "B" evaluate a different (cell 2) under these conditions
- If its not "A" or "B" and the string is "C" evaluate a different (cell 2) under these conditions
  (the only possibilities are A, B, and C)

Here is what I've tried:

1. `=IFS((D3="A",IFS((E2<=11,"L1"),(E2<=12.1,"L2"),(E2<=14.7,"L3"),(E2>14.7,"L4"))),OR(D3="B",IFS((E2<=11.8,"L1")OR(E2<=13.7,"L2")OR(E2<=14.6,"L3")OR(E2>14.6,"L4"))),OR(D3="C",IFS((E2<=15.8,"L1"),(E2<=17.8,"L2"), (E2<=19.8,"L3"), (E2>19.8,"L4"))))`
2. `=IFS((D3="A",(E2<=11,"L1"),OR(E2<=12.1,"L2"),OR(E2<=14.7,"L3"),OR(E2>14.7,"L4")),OR(D3="B",(E2<=11.8,"L1")OR(E2<=13.7,"L2")OR(E2<=14.6,"L3")OR(E2>14.6,"L4")),OR(D3="C",(E2<=15.8,"L1")OR(E2<=17.8,"L2")OR(E2<=19.8,"L3")OR(E2>19.8,"L4")))`

This formula does all but the first step of verifying the first cell and evaluating based on the contents of that cell:

- `=IFS(E2<=12.1,"L1",E2<=14.6,"L2",E2<=17.3,"L3",E2>17.3,"L4")`

Comment: Maybe its a good thing to know a bit more about this other cell, `E2`. Can you tell us more about the possible value of this cell, maybe using a screenshot in there too?

Comment: @user1037, as posted, you're asking others to set up our own sheet, type in data, create a solution and test it, then come back and try to explain the results. Please consider sharing a link to your sheet (or a copy of your sheet, or a representative sample from your sheet), being sure to set the link's Share permission to "Anyone with the link can edit." This would allow us to work with your actual data and leave solutions directly in your sheet. Others here may feel differently, but I myself would only be willing to jump in on this if a link to a sample spreadsheet is provided.

Answer (score 0):

`=if(D3="A",if(E2<=11,"L1",if(E2<=12.1,"L2",if(E2<=14.7,"L3","L4"))), if(D3="B",if(E2<=11.8,"L1",if(E2<=13.7,"L2",if(E2<=14.6,"L3","L4"))), if(D3="C",if(E2<=15.8,"L1",if(E2<=17.8,"L2",if(E2<=19.8,"L3","L4"))),"Not A, B or C")))`

---

The logic here is:

- IF D3="A", then

  - IF E2<=11, "L1", ELSE
  - IF E2<=12.1, "L2", ELSE
  - IF E2<=14.7, "L3",
  - ELSE "L4"
- ELSE IF D3="B", then

  - IF E2<=11.8, "L1", ELSE
  - IF E2<=13.7, "L2", ELSE
  - IF E2<=14.6, "L3", ELSE "L4"
- ELSE IF D3="C", then

  - IF E2<=15.8, "L1", ELSE
  - IF E2<=17.8, "L2", ELSE
  - IF E2<=19.8, "L3", ELSE "L4"
- ELSE D3 doesn't contain "A", "B" or "C"

Answer (score 0):

You were close you just needed to nest your IFS functions in IF functions or an additional IFS.

In both formulas below, `1` is a shorthand for `TRUE` for the last IFS condition.

#### Nesting in Two IF Functions

```
=IF(D3="A",
    IFS(E2<=11,"L1", E2<=12.1,"L2", 
        E2<=14.7,"L3", 1,"L4"), 
    IF(D3="B",
       IFS(E2<=11.8,"L1", E2<=13.7,"L2",
           E2<=14.6,"L3", 1,"L4"),
       IFS(E2<=15.8,"L1", E2<=17.8,"L2",
           E2<=19.8,"L3", 1,"L4"))
```

#### Nesting in One IFS Function

```
=IFS(
   D3="A",IFS(
      E2<=11,"L1", E2<=12.1,"L2",
      E2<=14.7,"L3", 1,"L4"), 
   D3="B",IFS(
      E2<=11.8,"L1", E2<=13.7,"L2",
      E2<=14.6,"L3", 1,"L4"),
   1,IFS(
      E2<=15.8,"L1", E2<=17.8,"L2",
      E2<=19.8,"L3", 1,"L4"))
```